# How to use nesting_ in SE case

Tags: r, tidyr, nse

I am struggling to learn how to program using the hadleyverse. I've read the NSE and lazyeval vignettes, but I'm still lost...

I'm trying to translate the example given on the tidyr::complete help page to an SE case.

```
df <- data_frame(
  group = c(1:2, 1),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2),
  item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = 1:3,
  value2 = 4:6
)
df %>% complete(group, nesting(item_id, item_name))
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to do the same thing with my variables specified as:

```
v1 <- 'group'
v2 <- 'item_id, item_name'
```

But before I try that, I need to be able to work it out using column names directly.
To get started, even though I know it's not what I want, this at least doesn't throw an error:

```
df %>% complete_(list(~group, ~item_id, ~item_name))
```

What I can't figure out is how to include the 'nesting_'
Things I've tried:

```
df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(~item_id, ~item_name)) 
# Error in nesting_(~item_id, ~item_name) : unused argument (~item_name)

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(list(~item_id, ~item_name)))
# Error: Each variable must be named. 
# Problem variables: 1, 2 

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(alist(~item_id, ~item_name)))
# Error: Each variable must be named. 
# Problem variables: 1, 2 

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(list('item_id' = item_id, 'item_name' = item_name)))
# Error in stopifnot(is.list(x)) : object 'item_id' not found

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(list('item_id' = df$item_id, 'item_name' = df$item_name)))
# No syntax error, but doesn't expand...

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(named_dots(item_id, item_name)))
# Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
# Problem variables: 'item_id', 'item_name'

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(list('item_id' = item_id, 'item_name' = item_name)))
# Error in stopifnot(is.list(x)) : object 'item_id' not found

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(list(as.name(item_id), as.name(item_name))))
# Error in as.name(item_id) : object 'item_id' not found

df %>% complete_(~group, nesting_(as.name(item_id), as.name(item_name)))
# Error in nesting_(as.name(item_id), as.name(item_name)) : 
#   unused argument (as.name(item_name))
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got `complete_` and `nesting_` to work together like this:

```
df %>% complete_(list(~group, ~nesting_(list(item_id = item_id, item_name = item_name))))
```

Looking at the code for `nesting_`, it looks like named list comes from the use of `tibble::as_data_frame`.

However, the code above doesn't help much when you actually start using your named variables.  Things still work with `complete_` OK:

```
df %>% complete_(list(as.name(v1), ~nesting_(list(item_id = item_id, item_name = item_name))))
```

And you can make the named list for `nesting_` via `setNames` and a vector of the names:

```
v2 <- c("item_id", "item_name")
df %>% complete_(list(as.name(v1), ~nesting_(setNames(list(item_id, item_name), v2))))
```

But I didn't find a solution to work with the list of names for `nesting_`.  My failures involved things like

```
df %>% complete_(list(as.name(v1), ~nesting_(setNames(lapply(v2, as.name), v2))))
```

> Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list. Problem
>   variables: 'item_id', 'item_name'

I didn't try much beyond that, but it may give you a starting point.

Comment: I'll still have to study ;-) But the question as I asked it is answered.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @aosmith 's suggestions, I hacked this workaround.
It's probably not the best/correct way, but it seems to work.

Starting with the last of his statements that do work:

```
v1 <- 'group'
v2 <- c("item_id", "item_name")
df %>% complete_(list(as.name(v1), ~nesting_(setNames(list(item_id, item_name), v2))))
```

I played around with the setNames call, to see what it did:

```
setNames(list(df$item_id, df$item_name), v2)
$item_id
[1] 1 2 2

$item_name
[1] "a" "b" "b"
```

and realized it was just subsetting the df columns named in v2. So  I tried to do the same thing via select_:

```
df %>% complete_(list(as.name(v1), ~nesting_(select_(., .dots = v2))))
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  group item_id item_name value1 value2
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <chr>  <int>  <int>
1     1       1         a      1      4
2     1       2         b      3      6
3     2       1         a     NA     NA
4     2       2         b      2      5
```

Comment: I couldn't come up with anything better either

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:

```
v1 <- 'group'
v2 <- c('item_id', 'item_name')
df %>% complete_(c(v1, ~do.call(nesting, lapply(v2, as.name))))

  group item_id item_name value1 value2
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <chr>  <int>  <int>
1     1       1         a      1      4
2     1       2         b      3      6
3     2       1         a     NA     NA
4     2       2         b      2      5
```

This doesn't use "SE" `nesting_()`, rather it takes advantage of the fact that the arguments to complete can be lazily evaluated. I'm not convinced this is preferable to [ap53's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363380/7050789), but it does remove the explicit use of `select()`.